# Read already created online meetings using Microsoft-Graph-Api thru C# code-403 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

[using docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp) I am trying to read/get all my meetings which i have created using microsoft-graph-api-c#.
using code :

```
var onlineMeetings = await graphServiceClient.Communications.OnlineMeetings.Request().GetAsync();
```

getting forbidden error 403
Or

```
var onlineMeetingsMy = await graphServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().GetAsync();
```

getting not found err.

Comment: Make sure you use [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) rather than [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions) requires Application permission `OnlineMeetings.Read.All`.

So you need to add the Application permission (not Delegated permission) in the Azure AD app.

[image]

Don't forget to click on **Grant admin consent for {your tenant}**.

Then you should use [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) to generate the `authProvider`.

Comment: ApplicationPermission /OnlineMeetings.Read.All. is already granted

Comment: @anu Please provide your code of generating `authProvider` and `graphServiceClient`.

Comment: @anu And share the decoded result of your access token in https://jwt.io if possible.

Comment: Getting error ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication); on this line:
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ClientCredentialProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @anu Make sure you add the SDK package correctly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-net-sdk

Comment: Thanx @Allen error resolved after adding graph auth sdk.but now below line using IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication); gives bad request error:var onlineMeetingsMy = await graphServiceClient1.Communications.OnlineMeetings .Request() .GetAsync();     here err.

Comment: @anu You seem not to specify the meeting id?

Comment: where to put meeting id?cant we retrieve list of meetings without specific id.I need list of meetings to display.

Comment: @anu We cannot list the meetings without id. When you create a meeting, you will get its id , and filter the id you can get the meeting. See the sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#request. Or you can use an external id to call this api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-createorget?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http.

Comment: I tried this var onlineMeetings = await graphClient.Communications.OnlineMeetings
 .Request()
 .Filter("VideoTeleconferenceId eq '123456789'")
 .GetAsync();but when i pass id/externalid it gives badreq err.Also when i tried this await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
 .CreateOrGet(externalId,chatInfo,endDateTime,participants,startDateTime,subject)
 .Request()
 .PostAsync();if i pass only id/externalid it create new meeting for todaysdatetime.i cant pass chatinfo,datetime which i may not know.hv to retrive details.

Comment: @anu @anu The first method seems not to work for filtering with `VideoTeleconferenceId`. You can directly use `Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings/{meeting id}`.

Comment: @anu `var onlineMeeting = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings["{meeting id}"].Request().GetAsync();`

Comment: var onlineMeeting = await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings["{meeting id}"].Request().GetAsync(); is working fine.Thanx for sharing.